# Converting an int parameter of type ProjectFile (user defined data type) to int of array

Tags: c#

I have an object of type ProjectFile as Follows:

```
var p = new ProjectFile();
```

This Object contains integer, string and bit.

Now I need to pass the integer type in this object to int of array

can some one help on this? `p` is the object containing the following parameters.

```
var p = new ProjectFile();
p.ProjectFileId = dbFile.ProjectFileId;
p.IsArchived = dbFile.IsArchived;
p.LastModifyDate = dbFile.LastModifyDate;
p.Checksum = dbFile.Checksum;
p.Size = dbFile.Size;
p.TimeStamp = dbFile.TimeStamp;
```

I need to pass the ProjectFieldId to a method which is taking int of array values.

Please help me on this. I am struggling with this from 3 days

Comment: Can you describe anything what is this object and what exactly do you want with code you tried ?

Comment: Add code for class `ProjectFile` or mention method name which take array of int.

Comment: this is the method which is taking int of array. In  that place I need to pass this ProjectFileId which is in allFilesWhichNeedsToUpdateInDbAfterUserSelection this object public void UpdateProjectFilesAsArchived(int userID, int projectID, Boolean isArchived, int[] projectFileIDs)

Comment: Added new code in answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

Then do it like this:

```
var p = new ProjectFile();
p.ProjectFileId = dbFile.ProjectFileId;
p.IsArchived = dbFile.IsArchived;
p.LastModifyDate = dbFile.LastModifyDate;
p.Checksum = dbFile.Checksum;
p.Size = dbFile.Size;
p.TimeStamp = dbFile.TimeStamp;
p.UpdateProjectFilesAsArchived(p.UserID, p.ProjectID, p.IsArchived, new int[] { p.projectFileIDs });
```